# ADF:Read ADF logger log messages in web application

Tags: oracle-adf

I am developing an embedded tool in my ADF fusion web application which will read and display the log messages of weblogic server.I discovered one file named `DefaultDomain.log` in `AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.7.40.67.80\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs` folder which contains all the log messages.

Now I want to write some logic to read the contents of this file dynamically and display it through the tool(ADF Faces).Is it possible to read this log messages through my java application?

If yes how to get the log file name from the weblogic server.I think the name of the log file is configurable in the server.This application is to be installed in various environments like clustered environment and also in activation /passivisation on

Comment: Yes ofcourse. Note that you can read your log files trough WebLogic as well (and propably all other application servers)

Comment: I need the application to be work in clustered environment also